# The other users: avahi, root, syslog, messagebus,, nobody, ntp, rtkit and whoopsie

Tags: ubuntu, users

What are all these other users (found them with top) when running Ubuntu:  avahi, root, syslog, messagebus, nobody, ntp, rtkit and whoopsie. I am aware that whoopsie, for example, is for reporting errors to Canonical.

When I run 'who' I only see me (terminal and graphical display).

Why don't they all run as root or as my user name? (I suppose that they run because I as a user needs them).

Comment: They don't run as root for the same reason you don't (or shouldn't be) do everything as root.  If a security exploit is found in one of your daemons, you dont want it having root access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of them are system daemons and can't actually log in, they represent processes started by [the init system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).  If you look at `cat /etc/passwd`, you'll see them all listed.  The last field is the default shell, which may be `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` indicating their lack of login possibilities.  The forth field (each field is separated by an `:`) is a comment that may provide some information about their purpose (for more, see `man 5 passwd`, the 5 is important, otherwise you'll get the section 1 `passwd` command; section numbers are described in `man man`).

[Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) services<sup>1</sup> run in the background, often as unprivileged users for security purposes -- this way undiscovered vulnerabilities can't be used to gain root access, etc.   Some of them use the generic `daemon` user, others create their own for more secure compartmentalization.

For example, Avahi is one such daemon, for broadcast and discovery of network services (e.g. certain kinds of file sharing, I believe) on a LAN.  NTP is another, for synchronizing the system clock with a WWW reference server.  On Ubuntu, services such as this can be enabled/disabled via **upstart** (an init system developed by Canonical).

`nobody` is a catch-all account for things intended to operate with no privileges beyond just existing.

---

<sup>1.  The ["Notable service daemons in Unix-like systems"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29#Notable_service_daemons_in_Unix-like_systems) section of that wikipedia article contains some things from your list.</sup>

Comment: I'd like to warn that although `nobody` or `nogroup` are named like that, they're still as regular user and group as the others. If 2 processes run as `nobody`, they own the same data, especially if they're both in `nogroup`. Or so I read.